# Cdbcriteria Join - Column Not Found

Tags: yii

I have the following SQL

`SELECT entry_subject.id, entry_subject.subject_id
FROM entry_subject
INNER JOIN subject
ON entry_subject.subject_id = subject.id
WHERE subject.id = 71`

I have arrived at the following which is an almost carbon copy of a number of examples, however I'm getting **1054 Unknown column 'EntrySubject.subject_id' in 'field list'**.

```
$subjectEntries = new CDbCriteria();
$subjectEntries->alias = 'EntrySubject';
$subjectEntries->select = 'EntrySubject.id, EntrySubject.subject_id';
$subjectEntries->join = 'INNER JOIN Subject ON Subject.id = EntrySubject.subject_id';
$subjectEntries->condition = 'Subject.id=71';
$subjectEntriesModel=Subject::model()->findAll($subjectEntries);
```

My relationships are as follows

```
return array(
'entrySubject' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'EntrySubject', 'subject_id'),
'phase' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Phase', 'phase_id'),
'subjectType' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'SubjectType', 'subject_type'),
);
```

What am I doing wrong?
Many thanks

Comment: are you selecting 'EntrySubject.id, EntrySubject.subject_id' from a 'Subject' model ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are trying to get subject entries for subject #71, then you should simply try the following :

```
$subject = Subject::model()->findByPk(71);
$subjectEntriesModel = $subject->entrySubject;
```

EDIT : you should, usually, avoid eager loading (as described in *miog* and *Burhan Çetin* answers) for a `HAS_MANY` relation

Answer (score 0):

From soju's answer above

> I assume you are trying to get subject entries for subject #71, then
>   you should simply try the following :
>
> ```
> $subject = Subject::model()->findByPk(71);
> $subjectEntriesModel = $subject->entrySubject;
> ```

I would suggest an addition to this.

```
 $subject = Subject::model()->with('entrySubject')->findByPk(71);
 $subjectEntriesModel = $subject->entrySubject;
```

**->with('entrySubject')** was added

This will allow yii to use one query instead if it is possible.

Comment: Eager loading for a HAS_MANY relation is, usually, not really efficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = Subject::model()->with('entrySubject')->findbypk($id);
```